# Amazon Advertising API for Sponsored Brands / Sponsored Products - is it possible to get report older than 60 days?

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I'm getting campaigns/adGroups reports from Sponsored Brands/Sponsored Products Amazon Advertising API. When I select reportDate older than 60 days, I'm getting the error "Report date is too far in the past. Reports are only available for 60 days." (code 406). Is it really not possible to get older reports? Or maybe older reports need to be queried differently? Also, isn't it possible to get the report for time period longer than one day in one request?

There is an information about "reportDate" parameter, that it is "The date for which to retrieve the performance report in YYYYMMDD format. The time zone is specified by the profile used to request the report. If this date is today, then the performance report may contain partial information. Reports are not available for data older than 60 days." - but is it for all reports always?

It seems strange to me, as other services normally offers more stats that 2 months, and also there is the note in the documentation, that "Note: New-to-brand metrics are calculated from November 1, 2018. If a report date is requested earlier than this date, the metrics will be calculated from November 1, 2018."

Thank you for explanation and your help!

Ela

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot get data older than 60 days through the API. The data does exist within Amazon's databases, but cannot be accessed via API.

If you have a vendor manager contact or something similar, it's theoretically possible to request this data from them, but they'd probably only do it as a one-off for a large client.

Comment: Have you ever tried this solution or was it just hypothetical?

Comment: @FedericoSala The company I work for recently has and for similar data, but these were for fortune 500 clients and very rare. For example, in vendor central a lot of the data is limited to 90 days, but you can cut a ticket to request the dataset for >=1 year. The data certainly still exists.